# Pickling all objects in python at once using globals()

Tags: python

I want to `pickle` all objects in my Python code at once without having to pickle them individually. I managed to `pickle` individual classes, but I was having problems when pickling `globals()`.

If I understand `globals()` correctly, then it is all objects and information put into a dictionary, right? So I tried pickling `globals()` like this:

```
with open('mypickle.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(globals(), f)
```

and I got the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 2, in <module>
    pickle.dump(globals(), f)
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'module'>: attribute lookup module on builtins failed
```

Any ideas why I am getting this error, and is there some better way of pickling the entire session besides globals? I want to keep running this script multiple times, and each time it is run it can get back to where it left off.

Comment: It is trying to pickle the `pickle` module, which is a global variable.

Comment: I had a hunch. Is there a way to prevent it from doing this? Thank you for your help!

Comment: You should consider using [`dill`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dill) which is meant for this use-case

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it out.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996118/python-shell-pickle-entire-state). In particular, you probab ly what the `dill.dump_session` method.